# How to concurrently check if any of multiple function calls returns true in C with pthreads

Tags: c, concurrency, pthreads, cancellation, any

This is a sample concurrent implementation of an "any" check:
to see whether any of a number of function calls returns true.
It works, but it waits for each function to finish
instead of halting the check as soon as a true value is found,
which is what I want.
The comments of the code below contain more information.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#define NUM_THREADS 32

// Flag which all of the concurrent functions can modify.
// Since they are only ever assigning it to true,
// there is no need to lock the data.
bool anyThing = false;

// Stores the output of each checkThing function.
// In a real use case,
// the checkThing function would be more complex
// than just looking up an entry in an array.
bool thingsToCheck[NUM_THREADS];

// This function is called NUM_THREADS times,
// and if any of them returns true,
// the program should print "Something returned true."
// Treat the contents of this function as a black box.
bool checkThing(long thingID){
  return thingsToCheck[thingID];
}

// A pthread can only run a void *(void *) function,
// so it accepts an ID (from 0 to NUM_THREADS-1) cast to a pointer.
void *checkWrapper(void *threadid) {  
  long tid = (long)threadid;
  if (checkThing(tid))
    anyThing = true;
  pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(){

  // Initialize the array.
  // This doesn't need to be done concurrently,
  // since it's only for the purpose of this minimal example.
  // Since two values of the array are true,
  // the anyThing flag should be true by the end.
  for (long i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++)
    thingsToCheck[i] = false;
  thingsToCheck[23] = true;
  thingsToCheck[24] = true;

  pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];

  // As mentioned before,
  // the checkWrapper function is passed an ID cast to a pointer,
  // which is the last argument of pthread_create.
  for(long i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++) {
    if (pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, checkWrapper, (void *)i)){
      printf("Error: unable to create thread #%ld\n", i);
      return -1;
    }
  }

  // Wait for each thread to end.
  // I believe this part needs to be modified to cancel all other threads
  // as soon as any checkThing function returns true.
  // Additionally, the checkWrapper function
  // should somehow signal the main thread to do so
  // if it ever gets a true value
  // (making the anyThing flag unnecessary).
  for(long i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++) {
    if (pthread_join(threads[i], NULL)){
      printf("Error: unable to join thread #%ld\n", i);
      return -1;
    }
  }

  if (anyThing)
    printf("Something returned true.\n");
  else
    printf("Nothing returned true.\n");

  return 0;
}
```

This is my first StackOverflow question, so I apologize if it has already been answered.

Comment: Do some research about *condition variables*. The first thread that "returns true" signals the condition variable, while the `main` thread waits for it. The threads can then be detached meaning they no longer needs to be joined.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thank you! I'll look into condition variables and detaching threads.

Comment: If you detach the threads, you wouldn't be able to safely re-use the variable `anyThing`, setting it to `false` for another round of checks. But you could cancel the threads and join them before the next round of checks.